# Apply Pay crashing in simulator in Xcode .07 and Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, applepay

I'm testing Apple Pay and trying to make a sample purchase, however when I'm in simulator in the XCode 7.0 and 7.1, there is an option of Pay with Passcode and it kept crashing simulator after you tap that..

Any ideas?

```
Process:               PassbookUIService [10809]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/Applications/PassbookUIService.app/PassbookUIService
Identifier:            PassbookUIService
Version:               1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [10692]
Responsible:           launchd_sim [10692]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-09-11 17:08:10.953 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        ECB58F9C-C22D-6885-D23E-251989A674E0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       A0D81423-EF8E-48CF-9C81-E81BF0FCF129

Time Awake Since Boot: 19000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6600 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderSet initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
CoreSimulator 182.4 - Device: iPhone 6s - Runtime: iOS 9.1 (13B5110e) - DeviceType: iPhone 6s

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001103b6f65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110743deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110287cfe -[__NSPlaceholderSet initWithObjects:count:] + 334
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102f7f9f +[NSSet setWithObject:] + 47
4   PassKit                             0x000000010ea6c47c -[PKPaymentOptionsDefaults setDefaultBillingAddress:forPaymentPass:] + 585
5   PassKit                             0x000000010eaf1bd9 -[PKPaymentAuthorizationServiceViewController _didAuthorizePaymentWithToken:] + 233
6   UIKit                               0x000000010edcb825 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
7   UIKit                               0x000000010ef32c8e -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: ug.  I'm having this too.  Is this a Yosemite vs El Capitan thing?  I'm still running Yosemite

Comment: Oddly, this works fine for me: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/samplecode/Emporium/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

By https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH5-DontLinkElementID_135

And in "Known Issues"

- Simulated transactions using Apple Pay in Simulator do not complete if requesting a user's billing address. (22551685)

We need to wait for the new version of Xcode, it would seem.

Comment: Thanks, updating to the latest Xcode (Version 10.0) fixed this for me